# Does StackOverflow own my questions?

Tags: copyright

I consider my questions brilliant and I want to reserve my rights to publish them in other forums.
Am I allowed to do that or do I need permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed in the [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal):

> 3. Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.

... and it goes on for another ~600 words if you want to fully understand your rights and obligations with respect to your contributions.

Comment: Thanks @feetwet. I had a quick read and I understand I can share my questions if I include hyperlink to them. Is that correct? They must need more traffic, that's why they allow that. Also, if it's the other way around surely Google will penalize them if I shared it with another forum beforehand. What would they do then?

Comment: @Thedude: Nothing so onerous.  You license your content to them, but it's still yours to use as you wish anywhere else.  3a-d simply explain how you can use the content of *other* people that you find on Stack Exchange, in compliance with the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.